# libgit2: Resolve merge conflict automatically

Tags: libgit2

I'm writing a program that is using libgit2 with a repo for management of config files across multiple instances. If there is a conflicting merge I would like to automatically resolve this (by picking the latest commits), without user interaction.

After performing a git_merge I get the git_repository_index and check if git_index_has_conflicts.
When I iterate over the conflicts I am able to get the git_index_entry for the contributing parts, but here is where my basic understanding of git falls short. My approach is to resolve what git_commit that relates to the git_index_entry and check the commit time to determine which entry to pick for merged solution. At the moment I'm a bit stuck on this so any pointers on how to go about doing or if there is a better approach to this problem is much appreciated.

I need to use the libgit2 API to solve this.

Here is some simplified sample code to show my approach:

```c
    void merge(const git_a_repository* a_repo, const git_signature* a_signature)
    {
      //Get the FETCH_HEAD annotated commit
      git_annotated_commit* annotated = nullptr;    
      git_object* obj = nullptr;  
      git_revparse_single(&obj, a_repo, "FETCH_HEAD");
      git_annotated_commit_lookup(annotated, a_repo, git_object_id(obj));
      git_object_free(obj);
    
      //Omitting git_merge_analysis for simplicity 
      //and assuming merge condition
    
      //Merge the FETCH_HEAD with HEAD
      git_merge_options merge_opts = GIT_MERGE_OPTIONS_INIT;
      git_checkout_options checkout_opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT;
      checkout_opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_FORCE 
        | GIT_CHECKOUT_ALLOW_CONFLICTS;
      git_merge(a_repo,(const git_annotated_commit**)(&annotated), 
        1, &merge_opts, &checkout_opts);
        
      git_index* index = nullptr;
      git_a_repository_index(&index, a_repo);
      //Handle conflicts
      if (git_index_has_conflicts(index))
      {    
        const git_index_entry* ancestor = nullptr;
        const git_index_entry* our = nullptr;
        const git_index_entry* their = nullptr;
        git_index_conflict_iterator* conflicts = nullptr;
        int err = 0;
        std::vector entriesToKeep;
    
        git_index_conflict_iterator_new(&conflicts, index);        
        while ((err = git_index_conflict_next(&ancestor, &our, &their, conflicts)) 
          == GIT_OK)
        {
          git_commit* ourcommit = nullptr;
          git_commit* theircommit = nullptr;
          //TODO: Need to find the commit belonging to git_index_entry
          //      to look up the comit time and use this to select
          //      which git_index_entry should be staged      
          //entriesToKeep.push_back(selectedEntry);
        }
        for (auto r : entriesToKeep)
        {
          git_index_add(index, r);
        }
        git_index_conflict_iterator_free(conflicts);
        git_index_conflict_cleanup(index);
      }
    
      //Commit merge         
      git_tree* tree = nullptr;
      git_oid tree_oid, commit_oid;
      git_index_write_tree(&tree_oid, index);
      git_tree_lookup(&tree, a_repo, &tree_oid);
            
      git_reference* head_ref = nullptr;
      git_a_repository_head(&head_ref, a_repo);    
      git_commit** parents = (git_commit**)(calloc(2, sizeof(git_commit*)));
      git_reference_peel((git_object**)&parents[0], head_ref, GIT_OBJECT_COMMIT);    
      git_commit_lookup(&parents[1], a_repo, git_annotated_commit_id(annotated));    
      git_commit_create(&commit_oid, a_repo, git_reference_name(head_ref), 
        a_signature, a_signature, NULL, "Merge", tree, 2, 
        (const git_commit**)parents);
      free(parents);  
      git_tree_free(tree);
      
      git_annotated_commit_free(annotated);
      git_a_repository_state_cleanup(a_repo);
    }
```

Comment: Try `git rerere` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere

Comment: If you used `git merge SOME_BRANCH`, I guess you could just use `git log -1 --pretty=format:%ct HEAD` and `git log -1 --pretty=format:%ct SOME_BRANCH` to get committer timestamps to compare? (or use %at instead if you want to use author timestamps)

Comment: Generally it's probably not a good idea to resolve conflicts automatically though. What if I add new config variable `ui.colour = blue`, and in parallell you add new config variable `db_server.ip = 192.0.2.42`. You merge your commit first. Then I merge commit, and there is a conflict. My committer date was later than yours, so my version is selected, and your `db_server.ip` config variable is essentially deleted. Is this really what is desired?

Comment: @Alderath, thank you for feedback. Generally I agree, but in my case the config files are changed from a tool and user can not add new fields, so changes are mainly to existing content and hence the approach of auto merging based on time of commit.